# How can I use the AnimateWindow function on a separate thread?

Tags: winforms, multithreading, winapi, animatewindow

How can I animate two windows at the same time? I tried:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int time, int flags);
...

AnimateWindow(panel1.Handle, speed, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_Top);
AnimateWindow(panel2.Handle, speed, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_Top);
```

But panel2 will not animate until panel1 finished its animation.

I must use the threading .. but i can't even if i used invoke .. also it runs the 2nd animation after the 1st

so how can i do it ?

Comment: From the [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx) msdn: `If the thread does not own the window. Note that, in this case, AnimateWindow fails but GetLastError returns ERROR_SUCCESS.`

Answer (score 1):

If both windows were created by the same thread, then the `AnimateWindow` function will run on that thread. According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669.aspx):

> The function will fail in the following situations:
>
> - If the thread does not own the window. Note that, in this case, `AnimateWindow` fails but [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

There is no way around this other than creating the second window on a separate thread. Additionally, you will have to call the `AnimateWindow` function from the thread that each window was created on.