# I want to Do Task Parallel in C#.net Winforms Application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've got 2 `Panels`. Both panels load a given time. Now i want to add some animation on both panels

```
// animation start of panel1
panel1.show();

// animation start of panel2
panel2.show();
```

After `panel1` finished it's animation, the 2nd panel animation starts. Soo now I want to animate both panels the same time.

I think multithreading can do that.
Can you show me how this could work in my particular in my case?

```
public static class Util { 
    public enum Effect { Roll, Slide, Center, Blend } 
    public static void Animate(Control ctl, Effect effect, int msec, int angle) 
    { 
         int flags = effmap[(int)effect]; 
         if (ctl.Visible) {flags |= 0x10000; angle += 180;} 
         else { 
              if (ctl.TopLevelControl == ctl) flags |= 0x20000; 
              else if (effect == Effect.Blend) throw new ArgumentException(); 
         } 
         flags |= dirmap[(angle % 360) / 45]; 
         bool ok = AnimateWindow(ctl.Handle, msec, flags); 
         if (!ok) throw new Exception("Animation failed"); 
         ctl.Visible = !ctl.Visible; 
     } 

     private static int[] dirmap = { 1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 10, 8, 9 }; 
     private static int[] effmap = { 0, 0x40000, 0x10, 0x80000 }; 

     [DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern bool 
        AnimateWindow(IntPtr handle, int msec, int flags); 
} 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
     Util.Animate(radPanel1, Util.Effect.Slide, 700, 360); 
     radPanel1.Show(); 
     expandablePanel1.Expanded = true;
}
```

Comment: Please show your animation code and where it is implemented.  Explicit multithreading may not be necessary depending on the complexity and nature of the animation.

Comment: what version of .Net you using? 4.0 has significant upgrades in threading management if your using this.

Comment: Considering that both animations will be done on the UI thread, I don't think that Parallel will help you in this case.

Comment: here is my code

http://db.tt/jHl5pn2F

Comment: @HiralBhimani - I've added your code to the post.  It is good practice to do this and not to add it as a link to dropbox, pastebin, etc.

Comment: Also, looking at your code now, this is specifically about a call to `AnimateWindow` - see here for your answer (voting to close as duplicate) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147086/how-can-i-use-the-animatewindow-function-on-a-separate-thread

Comment: Specifically, here, the answer is that this is not possible.  It is a limitation of the `AnimateWindow` function.  To get both controls animating simultaneously you would need to change your approach.

Comment: thnxxxx....i change my form and reduce the controls...so now everything work fine

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/aa983736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) component.

Comment: but how to apply in My case

Comment: Neither of these will work with the call to `AnimateWindow` since a background thread or timer would eventually end up marshalling the call to the UI thread which would, by design, have to run the calls in sequence.  `AnimateWindow` cannot be parallelized in any sane way within a single control.